# What is the connection between the two ways in which functions get represented as vectors when discussing inner product?

Tags: inner-products

When I interpret the inner product and orthogonality of two functions, I consider it the following way. Say you have a basis for a function space 
$\{\sin(x), \cos(x)\}$ and you have two vectors $u = (2,2)$ and $v = (-1,1)$ representing the functions $2\sin(x)+2\cos(x)$ and $-\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ respectively. 
These vectors $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal on the function space defined by the basis. Hence the functions they represent are orthogonal on some interval, in this case $[-\pi,\pi]$, why? I dont really know.

But that was just a side question, my main is that is in other texts I have seen when defining the inner product, the functions are being sampled at different points. A function $f(x)$ is sampled at points $t_0, t_1, ... t_n$ and it is represented by a vector $(f(t_0), f(t_1), ... f(t_n))$. And then you can represent another function  as the vector $(g(t_0), g(t_1), ... g(t_n))$. And define the inner product of the functions $f$ and $g$ as the dot product between these vectors as

$f(t_o)\cdot g(t_o) + f(t_1)\cdot g(t_1) + ... + f(t_n)\cdot g(t_n)$.

My question is what is the connection between the vectors $u,v$ and the sampled vectors? Both of these pairs of vectors represent the same thing. If the functions are orthogonal then dot product between these pairs are 0. But I still cant see the link between them.

I'll give an example of how the text I have read defines the inner product by sampling....

Consider $p(t) = 2t^2 - t + 1,   q(t) = 2t-1$. These functions can be defined on a function space by the basis {$1, t, t^2$}. And this is how my text defines the inner product between these functions, I quote:

"Step 1: You should first sample the polynomials at the values -1, 0, and 1. The
samples of each polynomial will give you a vector in $R^3$."

"Step 2: You take the dot product of the two vectors created by sampling. (As a
variation, this step could be a weighted inner product)"

Comment: Edited post, it was meant to be a multiplication

Answer (score 1):

You  can define the inner product between vectors (functions, in this case) in many ways, as long as the axioms are satisfied (see [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)). One way is by considering the integral of the product over a finite range, others multiply a third fixed function in, ... All those are *different* inner product spaces (as the inner product is different), even if the vector spaces (functions in your example) are the same; it makes little sense to try to use the inner product of one in the other.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting bogged down in switching back and forth between different spaces. Orthogonality is all defined in a single space. Looking at an example like yours, if you have a space with two orthonormal vectors $v_1,v_2$, and $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ are two orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $a_1v_1+a_2v_2$ is orthogonal to $b_1v_1+b_2v_2$. That comes about by expanding the inner product using bilinearity, and canceling out any terms which involve $v_1$ and $v_2$ using their orthogonality. Thus $(a_1v1+a_2v_2,b_1 v_1+b_2v_2)=a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 = 0$ by the orthogonality in the plane. But this only works if $v_1,v_2$ are orthogonal and have the same norm.

I don't think I understand your question about sampled functions.

Comment: With sampling I was just refering to representing the function as a vector with the functions values at different points

Comment: @ArnoldDoveman But that's not a representation of the whole function, it's just a vector constructed from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your $u$ and $v$ are finite linear combinations of some base functions.

The sample vector with components $f_i = f(t_i)$ is in general an approximation for $f$ and the one with components $g_i = g(t_i)$  in general an approximation for $g$.

It depends on the properties of $f$ and $g$ and the used number of samples, if the original functions can be reconstructed fully.
E.g. see [Whittaker-Shannon interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula).

So it could be the case (or not) that some function $f$ has an exact representation as $u$ and thus the two coordinates you mention, and some set of samples, which can be seen as $N$ coordinates.